# How to sort Arraylist data

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my code to sort my ArrayList's data

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
int firstNumber=int.Parse(txt1.Text);
int secondNumber = int.Parse(txt2.Text);
for (int i = firstNumber; i <= secondNumber; i++) {
    if (i%2==0) {
        myList.Add(i);
        lstbox1.Items.Add(myList);
    }
}
```

but when I run this program, this is happening:

[image]

Xaml Code

```
    <Grid>
            <TextBox x:Name="txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,15,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txt2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,58,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnOk" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="150,15,0,0" Click="btnOk_Click"/>
            <Label x:Name="lbl1" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="150,55,0,0"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="lstbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="10,102,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with sorting, but with your list being represented as string. What do you expect that happens when you put an `ArrayList` into a listbox? Shell all its items be printed? Just the first? It´s not at all determined, so .NET assumes just the type - in your case it prints `"Collection"`. What you want instead is an alternative `ToString`-representation of your list, but we don´t know what you *expect* the output to be.

Comment: Can you explain more ?can you share  XAML code too

Comment: ArrayList is deprecated. Consider using List<T> instead.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? I mean, I get that you're trying to add every 2nd item of a list inside a range, but what for? What are the objects you're trying to display? What do you expect to be displayed? In your example, myList is empty.

Comment: @Drakestar i understand you The program has no purpose. I didn't know arraylist so i want to do example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just

```
lstbox1.Items.Add(mylist);
```

Remove that and add

```
lstbox1.ItemsSource = myList;
```

**outside** of your for loop? You add your myList in your listbox in every even value. You just put your even values on your list, and make that list to listbox1's items source. Every value in your list, is added to your listbox1.